# Подвоєння приголосних в словах іноземного походження в українській і російській мовах

Tags: orthography, cross-language-comparison, подвоєння

Чому в словах іноземного походження (наприклад, class, professor, torlleybus, etc.) в українській мові приголосні не подвоюються, а в російській подвоюються?

В українській орфографії (наприклад, [тут](http://izbornyk.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm)) основним правилом є, що приголосні звичайно не подвоюються:

> 1. У загальних назвах іншомовного походження приголосні **звичайно не подвоюються**: *акумуляція, бароко, беладона, белетристика, бравісимо,
>    ват (хоч Ватт), грип, група, групето, гун (гуни), ідилічний,
>    інтелектуальний, інтермецо, колектив, комісія, комуна, лібрето,
>    піанісимо, піцикато, стакато, сума, фін (фіни), фортисимо, шасі, шофер*
>    та ін.
>
> **Тільки в окремих** загальних назвах **зберігається подвоєння**: *аннали,
> бонна, брутто, ванна (ванний), мадонна, манна (манний), мотто, нетто,
> панна, пенні, тонна, білль, булла, вілла, мулла, дурра, мірра.*

Російська орфографія (наприклад, відповідно до [повного академічного словника під редакцією Лопатіна](http://orthographia.ru/orfografia.php?sid=49)) містить правило:

> **§ 107.** Написание двойных согласных в корнях заимствованных
> (иноязычных) слов определяется **в словарном порядке**, напр.:
> *аббревиатура, акклиматизация, аккомпанемент, аккредитация, аккуратный,
> аллея, антенна, апелляция, аппарат, ассоциация, аттракцион, бацилла,
> брутто, буддизм, ванна, ватт, грамм, грамматика, грипп, группа,
> иллюзия, иллюстрация, иммиграция, ирригация, касса, кассета, киллер,
> класс, коллекция, колонна, комментировать, коммуна, компромисс,
> корреспондент, коррида, коррозия, коррупция, масса, металл, миссия,
> новелла, оппозиция, пицца, пресс, пресса, программа, профессор,
> раввин, спиннинг, стеллаж, суббота, терраса, террор, тонна, триллер,
> труппа, хлорофилл, хоккей, эксцесс, эссенция.*
>
> Ср. иноязычные слова с
> одиночными согласными: *алюминий, галерея, десерт, дилер, дилетант,
> импресарио, коридор, офис, официальный, офшор, рапорт, раса, софит,
> тореро, тротуар, штекер, эмиграция* и многие другие.

З чим це повязано? Чи було це правило в українській мові з самого початку, чи історично було подвоєння, але в наслідок того, що на практиці в подібних словах іноземного походження довгий звук не промовляється, під час реформи правила підкорегували?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Коротко: українська мова здебільшого уникала подвоєнь приголосних у запозичених словах, але внаслідок реформ правопису, здійснених з метою уподібнити правопис до російського, правило щодо подвоєння приголосних в таких словах було розширене.

---

### Правопис 1927

[Правопис 1927 року](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81), також відомий як "харківський" або "скрипниківський", містив наступні правила щодо подвоєння приголосних у словах іншомовного походження:

> Неподвоєні — подвоєні приголосні § 61. У чужих словах приголосні не подвоюємо: акумуля́ція, апара́т, асимілюва́ти, баля́ст, белетри́стика, гру́па, жира́фа, ідилі́чний, інтелектуа́льний, кому́на, су́ма, терито́рія і т. ін.
>
> Лише **в окремих словах** заховується подвоєння: а́вва, баро́кко, бру́тто, бу́лла, ва́нна, ві́лла, галло́, геє́нна, до́нна, мадо́нна, ма́нна, мо́тто, не́тто, оса́нна, ра́вві і деякі інші та звичайно **(між голосними) у чужих власних назвах**: Ґаро́нна, Ші́ллер, Мю́ллер, Ні́цца, Андо́рра, Аннам, Едда, Ме́кка, Ді́ккенс, Маро́кко, Алла́х, Па́тті, Та́ссо, Ганно́вер, Страде́лла, Ґа́ллія, Ціммерман, Сієрра, Еде́сса, Шеффілд і т. ін.

## Правопис 1933

[Правопис 1933 року](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1933_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) з метою більшої уніфікації із російським правописом того часу вніс помітні відмінності із попереднім варіантом 1927 року (на превеликий жаль тексту правопису знайти не вдалось):

> У правила внесено близько 126 поправок, *повністю змінено розділ про правопис іншомовних слів*

## Сучасний правопис

Текст використовуваного нині [правопису](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81#.D0.A3.D0.BD.D0.BE.D1.80.D0.BC.D1.83.D0.B2.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.BD.D1.8F_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.BF.D0.B8.D1.81.D1.83_.28XX_.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.BB.D1.96.D1.82.D1.82.D1.8F.29) було затверджено у 1990 році. Редакція 2012 року ([тут](http://www.pravopys.net/sections/89/) чи [тут](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm)) визначає розширений (порівняно із 1927) перелік випадків, коли у словах іншомовного походження відбуваєтсья подвоєння приголосних:

> § 89.Неподвоєні й подвоєні приголосні
>
> 1. У загальних назвах іншомовного походження приголосні звичайно не подвоюються: акумуля́ція, баро́ко, беладо́на, белетри́стика, браві́симо, ват (хоч Ватт), грип, гру́па, групе́то, гун (гу́ни), ідилі́чний, інтелектуа́льний, інтерме́цо, колекти́в, комі́сія, кому́на, лібре́то, піані́симо, піцика́то, стака́то, су́ма, фін (фі́ни), форти́симо, шасі́, шофе́р та ін.
>
> Тільки **в окремих загальних назвах** зберігається подвоєння приголосних: анна́ли, бо́нна, бру́тто, ва́нна (ва́нний), мадо́нна, ма́нна (ма́нний), мо́тто, не́тто, па́нна, пе́нні, то́нна, білль, бу́лла, ві́лла, мулла́, ду́рра, мі́рра.
>
> 2. При ***збігу однакових приголосних префікса й кореня*** подвоєний приголосний маємо лише тоді, коли в мові вживається паралельне непрефіксальне слово: апперце́пція (бо є перце́пція), іммігра́ція (бо є мігра́ція), іннова́ція (бо є нова́ція), ірраціона́льний (бо є раціона́льний), ірреа́льний (бо є реа́льний), контрреволю́ція (бо є револю́ція), сюрреалі́зм (бо є реалі́зм).
>
> Примітка. Коли непрефіксальне слово своїм змістом далеко відходить від префіксального (напр.: нота́ція — анота́ція, конота́ція), приголосний не подвоюється на письмі.
>
> 3. Подвоєні приголосні зберігаються **в географічних, особових та інших власних назвах**: Андо́рра, Гаро́нна, Голла́ндія, Кальку́тта, Маро́кко, Міссу́рі, Ні́цца, Ренн, Я́ффа; Бе́тті, Джо́нні, Мю́ллер, Руссо́, Фламмаріо́н, Ши́ллер.
>
> Примітка. Подвоєні приголосні зберігаються і в усіх похідних словах: андо́ррський (Андо́рра), марокка́нець (Маро́кко), я́ффський (Я́ффа).

Answer (score 2):

Базовий принцип 'як чуємо так і пишемо' пересилює збереження форми.

Це моя суб'єктивна інтерпретація явища згідно до мого суб'єктивного розуміння [теорії](http://www.nativlang.com/linguistics/optimality-theory.php) [оптимальності](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimality_theory)

Comment: -1: відповіді, які складаються з одного рядка і не містять посилань на поважні джерела, є лише суб'єктивною думкою автора, і тому не вітаються на StackExchange.