# Болард чи боллард?

Tags: іншомовні-слова, подвоєння

Не хотів створювати окрему тему задля одного слова іншомовного походження - **bollard**, але доводиться (перенаправлено з загальної [теми про подвоєння приголосних у словах іншомовного походження](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/187/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%94%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B2-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9-%D1%96-%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9/5958?noredirect=1#comment9545_5958)).

Доки не став шукати в інтернеті, [гадав](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E), що українською це слово буде з однією **л** - *бо**л**ард*, це навіть підтверджує [Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4). Однак, в інтернеті [перемогла форма](https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B4%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%8E) з подвоєним **л** - *бо**лл**ард*.

Намагався було знайти це слово у [«Словнику української мови» в 20 томах](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=191869&page=189), виданому Українським мовно-інформаційним фондом Національної академії наук України, але там його немає - є тільки слово *бола*.

То ж як буде правильно вживати це слово українською?

Answer (score 4):

У словниках цього слова не знайшла, але майже впевнена, що українською правильно - **болард** (без подвоєння).

У загальних назвах іншомовного походження букви на позначення приголосних зазвичай не подвоюємо (§ 128 [Українського правопису 2019 року](https://mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/05062019-onovl-pravo.pdf))

Тому правильно:

> *аба́т, акумулятор, баро́ко, беладо́на, белетри́стика, браві́симо, ват,
>   гру́па, гун (гу́ни), ідиліч́ний, інтелектуа́льний, інтерме́цо,
>   колекти́в, комі́сія, лібре́то, піані́симо, піцика́то, стака́то, су́ма,
>   фін (фі́ни), шасі́ та ін.*

Є список слів, які за традицією пишемо з подвоєнням. Наскільки я розумію, він вичерпний:

> *анна́ли, бо́нна, білль, бру́тто, бу́лла, ва́нна, ві́лла, до́нна,
>   мадо́нна, ма́нна, мулла́, панно́, пе́нні, то́нна, ду́рра, мірра та
>   слово Алла́х.*

Думаю, нам слід керуватися загальним правилом, і писати *болард* без подвоєння.

PS: Коли ви ґуґлите "боллард українською" у результати пошуку все одно потрапляють сторінки російською мовою. А російською, судячи з усього, якраз правильно "боллард" - тому і виходить, що результатів з подвоєнням більше. (Правила російської орфографії і пунктуації 1956 р. не вказують, що загальні слова іншомовного походження зазвичай пишуться без подвоєння - див. [§ 68](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/129-sogl-19-15))

Comment: Запитання містить посилання на [інше запитання](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/187/8) на нашому сайті, де є відповідь, яка, у свою чергу, дає розлогий огляд правопису подібних слів, згідно з різними правописами. Автор цього запитання знає загальне правило і, тим не менше, запитує про правопис цього конкретного слова. і тому, на мою думку, відповідь має бути зосередженою на **конкретному слові**, а не на загальному правилі.

Comment: @bytebuster написання цього конкретного слова залежить від загального правила. _Болард_ не знайти в словниках чи мовознавчих працях, а на вживання слова деінде покладатись не варто. Залишається Український правопис (на нову версію якого нема посилання в тій, іншій відповіді). Та якщо у вас є пропозиції, як зробити мою відповідь конкретнішою, я спробую до них дослухатися.