# Чи є в українській мові слово «сумуються» у контексті рахування?

Tags: значення-слів

Зустрічаю слово «сумуються» та словосполучення «не сумуються» на позначення чисел, які належить складати або не складати для одержання певного результату. [Наприклад](https://mon.gov.ua/ua/news/uryad-zatverdiv-proceduru-konkursu-za-yakim-obiratimut-chleniv-nacagentstva-iz-zabezpechennya-yakosti-vishoyi-osviti):

> (…) Далі бали сумуються та переводяться у конкурсну таблицю. (…)

Проте слово «сумувати» в словнику зустрічав лише в значенні «журитися»:

> **[СУМУВАТИ](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html?wrd=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)**, ую, уєш, недок. Пройматися почуттям суму, журби; удаватися в тугу, журитися. (…)

А в [цьому прикладі](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) натомість вжили «складаються»:

> - Якщо є стовпчик чисел, останнє (нижнє) число в якому підкреслене, то зазвичай йдеться про те, що всі числа у стовпчику складаються, а одержана сума записується нижче підкресленого числа.

Отже, чи можна вживати «сумуються» в значенні «складаються» щодо чисел?

---

Доповнення: цікаво, що [етимологічний словник](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) подає «сумуватись» у значенні «обговорювати, домовлятися, радитися» як запозичення з російської чи білоруської.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

СУМ (майже каламбур виходить :) ) ще пропонує слово ["підсумовувати"](http://sum.in.ua/s/pidsumovuvaty) у сенсі "додавати якісь числа".

Але питання, наскільки я розумію, не у тому, якими словами можна цю дію передати, а у тому, чи є "законним" саме слово "сумуватись" для позначення цієї дії. Якщо оцінювати виключно з точки зору словників, то, напевно, ні. Той же СУМ приводить ["сумування"](http://sum.in.ua/s/sumuvannja) лише як синонім до суму, але не до суми. У той же час, я не раз і не два зустрічав слово "сумувати" у значенні "додавати" (і від носіїв мови, і у технічних підручниках), тому думаю, що це цілком коректний варіант, який пора би вже і додати до словників.

Comment: На користь того, що це слово могло би вживатися щодо чисел говорить й те, що складно уявити випадок, коли значення слова не буде зрозумілим з контексту. Але я би його все-таки не вживав, особливо в офіційно-діловому та науковому стилях, оскільки воно видається просто калькою з російської, де слово «суммироваться» є в словниках.

Answer (score -3):

Мабуть, це є копiя вiд англiйського термiну "summation". Але питання в тому, що у вас у текстi варiант "сумувати" написаний з помилкою, та потрiбно вживати подвiйне М - "суммувати".

Наприклад: https://www.me.gov.ua/InfoRez/Details?id=cd804d21-cd17-4f0e-841b-573ba97e3390&lang=uk-UA має вiрний варiант "суммувати".

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до цього сайту! Ваша відповідь потребує уточнень: (1) копія іноземного слова не завжди означає, що слово «є в українській мові», а автор прямо запитує саме це; (2) В українській орфографії [основним правилом](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/187/8) є, що при запозиченні приголосні звичайно **не подвоюються**. Це правило має винятки, але, на жаль, ваш допис не доводить, що саме це слово є винятком; (3) якщо ви маєте інші джерела, які обґрунтовують ваші твердження, то такі джерела варто надавати разом із твердженнями. Необґрунтовані дописи отримують «мінуси» і заперечення.

Comment: погоджують із bytebuster. Словники також кажуть, що має бути *сумувати*. За вашим посиланням ми бачимо запитання надіслане приватною особою, тому граматика в ньому не показова.

Comment: Ставлю -1, тому що автор не спробував відредагувати відповідь згідно з коментарями. Якщо автор має складнощі з редагуванням, це можна обговорити у коментарях.